# Accessing WP8.1 Lumia 930 phone in 14.10

Tags: usb, 14.10, mtp, windows-phone

Is it even theoretically possible to access music files in WP8.1 Lumia phone with Ubuntu (or any other distribution)?

I think I've installed all the essential mtp related tools and libraries, but I can't even access the photos on my phone. If I connect my phone to my computer with USB cable and run mtp-detect, i get:

```
$ mtp-detect 
libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
```

My dmesg output (all of it) for the phone is:

```
[77805.920028] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[77807.724023] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[77807.857731] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fc
[77807.857735] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[77807.857738] usb 1-3: Product: Lumia 930 (RM-1045)
[77807.857740] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[77807.857743] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 51000000EDA4D7B00000000000000000
```

However, I can't access my phone in MTP or USB-storage mode. Am I missing something or is this pretty much impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. For my old Lumia 920 I could use gMTP or mtp-sendfile to transfer mp3 files to the phone. This does not work with the 930.

According to [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/1226/) it has to do with the device id not being recognized by the libmtp library. Until this is fixed, I use the "Music Drop" app to transfer music.